# Pip not included in Python3.6 on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, python, pip, matplotlib

When running `which python3.6`, I get `/usr/bin/python3.6`.

But when I try `python3.6 -mpip install matplotlib`, it says `/usr/bin/python3.6: No module named pip`.

I was informed that pip SHOULD be included in Python 3.4 and above. But why don't I have pip for Python 3.6? And how can I use it/get it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the python-pip package and the development tools:

```
yum install python-pip python-devel
yum groupinstall 'development tools'
```

If the python-pip package is not available or you need a later version - you could install the EPEL repository first, and then install the python-pip package

```
yum install epel-release
```

To install the lib

```
pip install matplotlib
```

**Note**:
If I remember correctly, yum the package manager is a python app, too. Be careful with updating packages (`pip install -U <package>`) with pip since it might break yum.

There are virtual environments ([virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)) for python development which is isolating your development python environment from the one on your system.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install python3-pip

you can also do this so you don't need to specify python3 (though it may potentially break something that explicitly wants 2.7):
alias python=python3

You are also missing a space:
python3.6 -m pip install matplotlib